# Get rid of "> > > > > > bash-5.1$" prefix in the results of a org babel code block

Tags: org-babel

Anytime I execute a code block with C-c it contains the following prefixed results:

```
#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
> > > > > > bash-5.1$ <result-output>
#+end_example
```

This is the configuration I'm using to cause the result from the above code block

```
#+begin_src bash :session kubectl :results output :var depends=kubectl-block
code-example
#+end_src
```

What's causing this and how do I get rid of this ugly output?

I'm using Doom Emacs on Mac OSX

Comment: Does your code block require the `:session` header? Sometimes that can cause unexpected formatting.

Comment: You are correct, that does seem to be the case.